# Nuxt3: Error using function inside defineEventHandler() in server/api/ file

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am trying to pass some authentication headers to fetch a third party API , but I am getting the following error when running a `/server/api/walmart.js` file in Nuxt3:

> [nuxt] [request error] this[D].init is not a function at new Sign
> (https://nuxt-starter-jzgdht.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.331c80ffab288536319518a60349d00207075dad.js:6:1135208)
> at Object.createSign
> (https://nuxt-starter-jzgdht.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.331c80ffab288536319518a60349d00207075dad.js:6:808197)
> at Scheme.sign (./node_modules/node-rsa/src/schemes/pkcs1.js:152:32)
> at RSAKey.module.exports.Key.RSAKey.sign
> (./node_modules/node-rsa/src/libs/rsa.js:264:40) at
> NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.sign
> (./node_modules/node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js:318:32) at
> generateWalmartHeaders (./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:446:28) at eval
> (./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:458:14) at eval
> (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:364:14) at Object.eval [as handler]
> (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:564:12) at eval
> (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:475:31) [nuxt] [request error]
> this[D].init is not a function at new Sign
> (https://nuxt-starter-jzgdht.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.331c80ffab288536319518a60349d00207075dad.js:6:1135208)
> at Object.createSign
> (https://nuxt-starter-jzgdht.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.331c80ffab288536319518a60349d00207075dad.js:6:808197)
> at Scheme.sign (./node_modules/node-rsa/src/schemes/pkcs1.js:152:32)
> at RSAKey.module.exports.Key.RSAKey.sign
> (./node_modules/node-rsa/src/libs/rsa.js:264:40) at
> NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.sign
> (./node_modules/node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js:318:32) at
> generateWalmartHeaders (./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:446:28) at eval
> (./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:458:14) at eval
> (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:364:14) at Object.eval [as handler]
> (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:564:12) at eval
> (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:475:31)

```
import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';

const keyData = {
  consumerId: '<consumer id removed for this post>',
  privateKey: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAiDffvTlnBcHfDhPjYlJhSk+atPFE6HpFaf4mm/aYBXmOn89A
  MMulkkmpu+RGj0SaPrpX/ockoSeMuuEPPd3AQ5uZAnJw9TBnE2/kJrPsHaKyVFGV
  hZneksIK/KdP/kpGSuVAkocPdit5zKwliMnc6/GVLpDFvU8K2QPnvYu2Jp8XBDwg
  gTu2tzHQkrm0cdCYZklKKqN9NdVLJy+6AL50+vX19nHwDdCYCvnPtH/hXxMwRnIJ
  3qibO8owPWh+q/xMld2K2OoUNWpbsxBj/r9Jxu60d429+XcIUu1hyPHG1lDKiK/n
  Z4L+7WE4Ez8sEVD0YrE9hRRbLl5Dsvi4XZrG9QIDAQABAoIBAQCFNN5+1JuCbcwK
  oDhD9fteB+pp92ZDUQ6AUCDBc6vF7tEiRjGnhf4ryA1LyDeX8qZDoUZbiRyw21Qr
  i9qzzR4u/wHp+q+rleG2iDy7/EZx1KA/BGkLdSTKrya/W35GVavXocg7gggErw80
  r0MlOQHpWR1hpAE61wjsn30HRpChwow1YZE/6cMIQN2nCJ+JGXuZDoGazYk4HwFD
  Fmrtag/FjShYUVgr4QlrPzYzcTCKX1UKQkZ9AED9Q2prKSvoD8ZxOJSaVF0FP1ty
  /i9L1I/eJEusSBPXc9v5xJjs7q8RRKZhn3TuvBHos3LDuaQKwPBe+w0vHr8ZVw5t
  tuZPiq8BAoGBAOYILkVnnrskg2qzqewHukiKnZHLi+WkJQPQzTHvVMMCEUaxF+6p
  Y58tLlaEd0uNH1ntDPya5s2y01/1eZ/8n1U1/SlqKoQ5apkC77eNBklMxixJ0xGP
  zu1bj5COba6pXdY+YcW2z7W0ubmPD3YCSD/VUD/IKXwTEAHm2J11ffM9AoGBAJeY
  hRbiSQW6GXWHu41qqIYsWfdJpy/A0qhpXjmySq1XFH/ThHDuFmn5RkZVvn7D/Pql
  GfO8E55QWjK+SLO7LBRazKP0GNmrKinVMKyo7WUgwrZy3fwEY5wcNaNFB/YL9J4M
  OSRp6eV3pnUwQI2NhzTzuHAyJgd/r+I6zMeSTn4ZAoGADGhejpHTRwbmK8g7Hycf
  jjAj5axUBHQBJx6JIutk6AvhgK2mu9HZNMnMGRCWGrYm/cPCkpGMZ4YAzsk/4ThQ
  I9mAqU43suAh9tTotz7dGvEQM21b/DOEltr8eHCmS+iIzjiZL3/33jY8Wlz0GYpv
  +Tl5VadnTXD9yQx5nKysuYUCgYA6PNy8Kth0u8a2ERvrOxNc4EL7ri7tOH11N218
  atMnfnGgnciefcjck2f880nId1CDldO/f/xlcGcGYXWanohTlYJSZh752DjNc1pM
  qmTw2cITx1MiUylVOr0caROi4XrrELUPGSVDA1FOaegSuVE89XhgmdNkRBh0p7Qt
  4zYGWQKBgFGuZgbPl76K3fj5POY5OlPusXdCCqJMHKPug+4e5mG82T1KvLFCj1PQ
  Fm0y9PoS3A8SXf+aEeLhRqVrpaU4w5RK8PqeF6IB2hpDrHJ8b+3ERU3J7/KuU8Vw
  pmwDIbjWypH4dNJgRMti+RKDb9llup6xP5Q4PQRzvUQdklSCp3D8
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`,
  keyVer: 1,
};

const generateWalmartHeaders = () => {
  const { privateKey, consumerId, keyVer } = keyData;
  const hashList = {
    'WM_CONSUMER.ID': consumerId,
    'WM_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP': Date.now().toString(),
    'WM_SEC.KEY_VERSION': keyVer,
  };

  const sortedHashString = `${hashList['WM_CONSUMER.ID']}\n${hashList['WM_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP']}\n${hashList['WM_SEC.KEY_VERSION']}\n`;
  const signer = new NodeRSA(privateKey, 'pkcs1');
  const signature = signer.sign(sortedHashString);
  const signatureEnc = signature.toString('base64');

  return {
    'WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE': signatureEnc,
    'WM_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP': hashList['WM_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP'],
    'WM_CONSUMER.ID': hashList['WM_CONSUMER.ID'],
    'WM_SEC.KEY_VERSION': hashList['WM_SEC.KEY_VERSION'],
  };
};

export default defineEventHandler(() => {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: generateWalmartHeaders(), // <--- the error seems to originate from this

  return {
    api: 'works',
    options: options,
  };
});
```

Am I not using the defineEventHandler() correctly there?

Comment: Have u solved this?

Answer (score 0):

@redshift,

1.The const 'options' in the defineEventHandler() function has not closing tag (unterminated).

2. Keep in mind we're working in server side here, check your functions within generateWalmartHeaders(). Are they all functioning in the backend ?
3. Fire this code with hard coded headers , and see if it runs / debug it.
4. Check Docs - they changed the documentation 20th of June sometime later than u posted this question.
5. check this example...

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  return {
    api: 'works'
  }
})
```

6. Check my working example , maybe it will help you get on your way :

```js
const config = useRuntimeConfig()

let environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
let $endpoint = environment == 'development' ? 'http://dev.endpointisdev/' : 'http://prod.production/';

console.log('ENVIRONMENT =', process.env.NODE_ENV)
console.log('$ENDPOINTS =', $endpoint)

export default defineEventHandler(async(event) => {

  const productsRequest = await $fetch(`${$endpoint}` +'somelistrequest', { 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${config.auth_user}:${config.auth_pw}`),
      'guiId': '7552662'
    },
    body: {
      reference : "blablabla", // 
      productListRequest : {
      securityKey : `${config._key}`
      }
    } 
  });
  return responseObject.list
})
```

7. IMPORTANT :
   I fire this from my store with something like this ..
   Now i've encountered a situation today where deployment to production made this api call fail because it needed to be **"camelCase"**
   let submitOrder = await $fetch("/api/**submitOrder**", {method: 'POST', body: orderPayload});